# Local URL fallbacks for offline development

Tags: css, macos, proxy, fallback

I often work from remote, in the train or on places where I don't have any or a stable internet connection. Our app loads some fonts, CSS and JS from different CDNs (google and microsoft). When I'm offline I don't have access to this files and can't work properly.

Even worse, when I have a bad internet connection, my browser waits till it runs in a timeout, and this slows down everything.

> Is there a solution where I can set up a local fallback for some URLs and server this content when no internet connection is available?

I'm on OS X, and maybe there is some proxy stuff out there I don't know which can handle such a thing. btw: HTTP would be enough, so no dealing with SSL would be necessary for development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [a great answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21765/how-do-i-get-a-production-website-to-load-assets-from-local-web-server) to a similar question on the webmasters StackExchange site. In short, you can use [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to redirect certain requests to a local file. Should work well, as long as it's not a massive list of assets you have (or dynamic requests).

Alternatively, you could just use a build script of some sort (depends on your toolchain) to rewrite the asset URLs to local versions (and of course make sure they're pointing to the proper versions when committing code).

Comment: thanks for your answer, charles proxy looks promising!